# Angular UI didn’t pickup data model change when the project has BrowserAnimationsModule

Tags: angular, animation, data-binding, module

My project have a page to select a program. It works perfectly until I add BrowserAnimationsModule into my project.

The page has a button “change to Program A”. It is always working correctly no matter how many time you click this button.

Please see [correct program selector](http://www.justa999.com/multiple/#/program-selector)

But it will set to “Empty Program” on the second click after BrowserAnimationsModule is added into this project. But the data model is already set to correct program which I printed on the page.

Please see [broken program selector](http://www.justa999.com/brokenMultiple/#/program-selector)

This page itself didn’t use BrowserAnimationsModule. The code is exact the same on both link  except broken one has BrowserAnimationsModule in the project.

I tried Firefox and Edge, both have the same issue.

I also tried Angular version 12 and 15, both have the same issue.

Current implementation is using FormControl. I also tried [(ngModel)] and get the same issue.

Both links have source map and can debug on the source.
Please use browser console to see them.

I saw someone mentioned [a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18430) on  BrowserAnimationsModule. But seems it was fixed.

You can get full control on this small project [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-mrngkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: You can get full control on this small project on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-mrngkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why?

You're updating `allProgramList` that causes Angular rendering engine to apply changes to `ngFor` diffs. It sees that array has changed and tries to rerender it. First, it removes items from the DOM, then adds new items one by one(due to missed `trackBy` option).

The difference is in a call `renderer.removeChild`:

When using `BrowserAnimationsModule` it uses `BaseAnimationRenderer` that only marks item to be removed after transition.

You could see in browser smth like:

[image]

By default Angular uses `DefaultDomRenderer2` that removes item immediately.

After removals Angular inserts new nodes and registeres built-in `NgSelectOption` directive on each of `<option>` tag that also updates `<select>` value based on `_optionMap`(provided by `[ngValue]`) or `-1` when `_optionMap` is not provided.

So, consequence of those operations leads to wrong final value of `<select>` html element.

### Solutions:

You could try one of these options to fix it:

1. Use `trackBy`

```
// html
*ngFor="let p of allProgramList; trackBy: trackByFn"
```

```
// ts
trackByFn(i, x) {
    return x.pId;
}
```

2. Use `ngValue` instead of `value` property binging on `option` tag

```
// html
[ngValue]="p.pId.toString()"
```

Comment: trackBy solution doesn't work, But ngValue solution works,

Comment: @Justin TrackBy case https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-vzdkxf

Comment: TrackBy works on my demo project. But it doesn't work on my real project which is much more complicated. I can't bring my real project here. At least ngValue is working on my real project. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush to ProgramSelectorByClientComponent to see what happens.

This might not fix the problem, but it's a good start for debugging your issue.

Answer (score 0):

##### TLDR; Execute `this.cd.detectChanges()` when array is replaced ([stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-sfz1vt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogram-selector-entry%2Fprogram-selector-by-client%2Fprogram-selector-by-client.component.ts)).

---

Everytime you call the following line, your code destroys and recreates your whole options inside the `select`, that means that any previous values setted to the `FormControl` saved at `selectedProgram` are lost:

```
// line inside `loadPrograms()` method
this.allProgramList = res;
```

I see that you tried to fix this by calling the `followProgram()` method everytime your options are reset, which might be okay. But it might cause issues when an animation is involved -even though there's no actual animation-, this kind of bug (the kind of ones solved by calling `detectChanges()` at certain points), are often related to DOM not being updated soon enough when your code needs to.

My guess is that, by adding the module it "enhances" the `select` behaviour, by delaying a bit the `option` array creation. Not giving enough time for it to be fully created when you try to set your new value. So, there's three solutions I can think of...

I tested [all of them](https://imgur.com/a/uSzEz3g), I added an stackblitz example for each one of them.

##### 1. Call `this.cd.detectChanges()` just after replacing your array([stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-sfz1vt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogram-selector-entry%2Fprogram-selector-by-client%2Fprogram-selector-by-client.component.ts))

This will force your select to be fully rendered when being accessed in further steps:

```
// line inside `loadPrograms()` method
this.allProgramList = res;
this.cd.detectChanges()
```

##### 2. Call `setTimeout(() => {...}, 1)` ([stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-wxw9xs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogram-selector-entry%2Fprogram-selector-by-client%2Fprogram-selector-by-client.component.ts))

This will give "time" for the delay to be handled in a separate lifecyle change detection run ([this is a deep subject](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)),

```
// line inside `loadPrograms()` method
setTimeout(() => {
    this.followProgram();
},1)
```

##### 3. Do not replace your whole array, just push the new values ([stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-b5fkw8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogram-selector-entry%2Fprogram-selector-by-client%2Fprogram-selector-by-client.component.ts))

This will make Angular to NOT destroy your dom, that way it won't be necessary to wait for another lifecycle to set the value:

```
// line inside `loadPrograms()` method, do the following 4 lines instead of just `this.allProgramList = res`
res.forEach((item) => {
    if (!this.allProgramList.find((p) => p.pId === item.pId)) {
        this.allProgramList.push(item);
    }
});
```

---

My final comment about this thing, would be to encourage you to [report it as a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/new/choose), just adding an extra module shouldn't change behaviour this way.

Comment: I tried those solutions before, didn't work.

Comment: @Justin, is there any difference in your tests from the stackblitz example you shared?? it's the only explanation I can find... I mean, the 3 stackblitz examples I shared do work ([see here](https://imgur.com/a/uSzEz3g)).

Comment: Your solutions works on my demo project. But it doesn't work on my real project which is much more complicated. I can't bring my real project here. I saw Yurzui's ngValue is working on my real project. His solution is also more graceful. So I have to give the bounty to him.  Thanks a lot for your solutions!